# Unable to resolve hg merge conflict when using vimdiff

Tags: merge, mercurial, vimdiff

I am using the default version of mercurial without much modifications. By default it uses "vimdiff" for the purpose which I wasn't familiar with. I am going to explain the situtation:

After 1st commit on *default* branch:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main
```

After 1st commit on *xyz* branch:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

After 2nd commit on *default* branch:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX(x, y)     (x > y ? x : y)

int main
```

Expected code after merging xyz branch into default branch:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX(x, y)     (x > y ? x : y)

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

In what way should I accept/discard hunks/diffs/parts of code to obtain the expected result either in vimdiff or ediff. If there is an alternative way to solve this problem then please share.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mercurial has a set of default mergetools it will search for. If it proposes `vimdiff`, it is because either it doesn't find any other tool or because you have specified it in your `$HOME/.hgrc`.

The page https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MergeToolConfiguration and `hg help mergetool` explain the syntax to use to specify a mergetool. I suggest to use KDiff3, which is a cross-platform GUI merge tool.

Then you have to get familiar with the KDiff3 usage, but it is a GUI so you can just explore it. It also has many keyboard shortcuts if one wants to use them.